# `window not defined` error in nextjs middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, appwrite

Stack I'm using:

- **Appwrite** (Backend)
- **Next.js**

I'm using Next.js middleware to implement some protected routes. In the `middleware.ts` file, I've added a method that checks whether the user is logged in. After adding that, it's showing the `window is not defined` error. But I haven't used `window` anywhere in the method. Below is the main content of `middleware.ts`

```js
    const NOT_LOGGED_IN_ROUTES = ["/login"];
    const LOGGED_IN_ROUTES = ["/edit-profile"];

    export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      const currentPath = request.nextUrl.pathname;

      const { AppwriteServices } = await import("@/AppwriteServices");
      const appwriteServices = new AppwriteServices();
      const isUserLoggedIn = (await appwriteServices.getCurrentUser()) !== null;
      
      if (isUserLoggedIn && NOT_LOGGED_IN_ROUTES.includes(currentPath)) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
      }

      if (!isUserLoggedIn && LOGGED_IN_ROUTES.includes(currentPath)) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
      }
    }
```

if the user is logged in, the `getCurrentUser` method returns the user data, otherwise `null`. Below is the content of `getCurrentUser`

```js
  getCurrentUser = async () => {
    try {
      await this.setSession();

      return await account.get();
    } catch (error) {
      // throw new Error((<Error>error).message);
      /*
        Cannot throw an error here,
        cause in Appwrite's `account.get()`,
        catch means the user is not logged in.      
      */
    }

    return null;
  };
```

Above used `setSession` method is shown below

```js
private async setSession() {
    try {
      const cookieValue = await this.getCookieValue();

      const authCookies = {
        [`a_session_${AppwriteProject.toLowerCase()}`]: cookieValue,
      };

      client.headers["X-Fallback-Cookies"] = JSON.stringify(authCookies);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error((<Error>error).message);
    }
  }
```

Above used `client` is the client object provided by `appwrite`. And the `getCookieValue` method is shown below

```js
private async getCookieValue() {
    try {
      const { cookies } = await import("next/headers");

      const sessionNames = [
        `a_session_${AppwriteProject.toLowerCase()}`,
        `a_session_${AppwriteProject.toLowerCase()}_legacy`,
      ];

      const cookieStore = cookies();
      const hash =
        cookieStore.get(sessionNames[0]) ??
        cookieStore.get(sessionNames[1]) ??
        null;

      return hash?.value || "";
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error((<Error>error).message);
    }
  }
```

The `AppwriteProject` variable used above is just an env variable.

I had to set the sessions manually cause `Appwrite` uses `localStorage` to store and retrieve session tokens and I'm doing everything on the server-side.

So as you can see above, I haven't used `window` anywhere in the method/s. There are some `appwrite` provided methods as well. the `account.get()`, which source code you can check [here](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/blob/9463607067dbba35ea71aa55a6b70f26ca7fe60e/public/sdk-web/services/account.ts#L21)

In the `account.get()` method, another [`client.call()`](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/blob/9463607067dbba35ea71aa55a6b70f26ca7fe60e/public/sdk-web/client.ts#L361) method is used, where we can see some use of the `window` object. But it's not used directly. There are fallback [checks](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/blob/9463607067dbba35ea71aa55a6b70f26ca7fe60e/public/sdk-web/client.ts#L373) with `if` statements. So there's no way for the `window` object to get executed.

Besides that, I'm using the same `getCurrentUser` method on another server component and that works fine.

Can't understand what's the issue here. Any help will be appreciated. Also, let me know if you need any further info

Comment: - What is the stacktrace?

Comment: shows `node_modules/isomorphic-form-data/lib/browser.js (1:17)`

Comment: after following the stacktrace, i noticed that Appwrite uses the `isomorphic-form-data` library that's using the `window` object in their `browser.js` file. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 contexts where your code can run when you make a Next.js app

1. Client side (browser)
2. Server side (hosting server)
3. Edge (edge networks)

The Appwrite web sdk (appwrite NPM package) uses isomorphic fetch so that the same fetch can be used in both client and server side, but it doesn't work on the edge.

For now, I would suggest not using the web sdk in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the window object you need to use it in a client component and wrap it in a `window != undefined`.

Note: It can’t be used in a sever component or in a Next JS middleware.